# Символы в url и email

Tags: валидация

Доброго времени суток!
 У меня такой вопрос:
 
- какие символы поддерживаются в **url** и **email**? 
 - какие могут быть?
  - все ли символы в **utf-8** можно использовать для **url** и **email**?

Comment: [URI](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986)

[email address](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4.1)

Comment: Если Вас, по простому, интересует кириллица - то нет, ни в utf-8, ни в какой-либо однобайтной кодировке.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38787343/2914140. Заодно можно посмотреть, какие бывают email.

Answer (score 3):

Ниже перечислены символы, которые можно применять в URL для имен контекстов и идентификаторов:

```
Алфавитно-цифровые символы:
  a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
Специальные символы:
Описание     Символ
Дефис   -
Подчеркивание   _
Точка   .
Восклицательный знак    !
Тильда  ~
Звездочка   *
Одинарная кавычка   '
Открывающая и закрывающая скобки    ( )
```

[источник](http://wiki.eelu.edu.eg/wps/iehs/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wp.admin.help/admin/h_url_valid_chars.html)

Для E-Mail

Описание Это регулярное выражение для проверки email адреса. Основные пункты:

1) Разрешены имена пользователей в email с 1 или 2 буквами, а также 3 и более. Разрешены символы "-", ".", "_" в середине ника пользователя email.

Не разрешено:

Имя пользователя не может начинаться с символов "-", ".", "_" или любого не буквенного символа.

2) Разрешены любые иерархические домены. Например: admin.office.com. Правила символов такие же как и в 1-м пункте.

3) Разрешается от 2 до 9 символов в TLD имени домена.

4) Не разрешены адреса с указанием IP.

[источник](http://regexlib.ru/email/16-reguljarnoe-vyrazhenie-dlja-proverki-email.html)

Comment: Статья по вашей ссылке чрезмерно упрощает положение вещей. Вот [немного больше](http://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/276994) деталей.

Comment: А вот упрощённая регулярка, описывающая адрес email по RFC822: http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: По мне так на стороне клиента проверка может быть минимальной. Вплоть до простейшего `^.+@.+$`. Потому как единственный нормальный способ проверить - послать письмо и ждать подтверждения. Ну и перед этим можно MX посмотреть, нет - выдать юзеру ошибку.